# How to configure grails to use single transaction manager for multiple datasources?

Tags: grails, spring-boot

I have a Grails 3.1.5 application that uses two different datasources. My intention is to use 2-phase commit / XA transactions between these two datasources. I have declared them in application.yml as:

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
        jmxExport: false
        jndiName: "java:/applicationUserDS"
    other:
        dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
        jmxExport: false
        jndiName: "java:/otherUserDS"
        name: "other"
```

However, when I run the application within JBoss EAP 6, I notice that Spring is attempting to use a ChainedTransactionManager because there multiple transaction manager beans: `ChainedTransactionManagerPostProcessor.getTransactionManagerBeanNames(registry)` returns `[transactionManager, transactionManager_other]`.

Is there a way to configure grails/spring boot so that it only creates one transaction manager and uses it for both datasources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the transaction manager used by specifying a `transactionManager` bean in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`

You would need to configure a `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager` and set `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform` to `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform` in your configuration.

You would probably also have to set `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringJtaSessionContext`

Comment: Are those properties I add to application.yml, or somewhere else? ... When you "configure a JtaTransactionManager", do you just mean adding those properties, or is there more involved? It has been very hard to find specific steps for configuring this when I have searched online.

Comment: Something I'm also confused about is that the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) seems to indicate that a vendor-specific subclass of JtaTransactionManager isn't needed for JBoss: "For typical JTA transactions, a plain JtaTransactionManager definition is all you need, portable across all Java EE servers. There is no need to configure a server-specific TransactionManager lookup for this kind of JTA usage."

Comment: The `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform` and `hibernate.current_session_context_class` are configured in `grails-app/conf/application.yml` yes